# setting a property being passed as a parameter to null

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I have the following method:

```
    public bool Method(object obj){
     var objType = obj.GetType();
     //do some reflection to get obj properties for some logic
     ...
     if(someCondition) {
      obj = null;
      return false;
     }

     if(condition2){ return true;}

     return false;
    }
```

Method call:

```
var someObj = SomeObj();
Method(someObj.someProperty);

public class SomeObj : IEntity{
 public SomeProperty someProperty {get;set;} //this needs to be set to null in some conditions
}
```

I would like to have a general method that takes in all types of Entity objects, that's why it's of "object" type. Then I would like to get its type, and go through all the properties to perform some logic. In the end, based on certain condition, I would like to set the object passed in to null. However, the problem is that the object passed in is always a property of some other Entity object, so I can't set it to ref. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already used reflection to determine property info, performance most likely isn't your top concern.  You can pass the object and the prop name (since you used reflection to get the obj properties already) and set it to null.

```
var a = new TestA();
a.Prop.Id = 1;

Method(a, "Prop");

Console.Write(a.Prop);

public bool Method(object obj, string propName)
{
    // if condition is met
    obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(obj, null);
    return false;
}

public class TestA
{
    public TestB Prop { get; set; } = new TestB();
}

public class TestB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

In the above example, `a.Prop` will be null.

Answer (score 0):

### Pass an expression

You aren't currently passing a property into `Method`. You are passing the *value* of the property. The method has no idea what the original property is and therefore cannot set it to null.

To get around this, you can pass in an `Expression` representing the property instead of the property's value. Then your method can parse the expression and do whatever is needed, including reading and setting the value.

So instead of doing this

```
var someObj = new SomeObj();
Method(someObj.someProperty);  //Obtains the value of the property and passes it
```

The caller would do this:

```
var someObj = new SomeObj();
Method(() => someObj.someProperty);  //Passes an expression representing the property
```

To modify `Method` so that it can work this way, you have to do a little bit of expression parsing, but not much:

```
static public bool Method<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression) where T : class
{
    var memberExp = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    var propertyInfo = memberExp.Member as PropertyInfo;
    var targetObject = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(memberExp.Expression).Compile()();

    Console.WriteLine("Old value is {0}", propertyInfo.GetValue(targetObject));

    if (someCondition1)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(targetObject, null); //Set it to null
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you plan to call this frequently and you're worried about the performance of `Compile()`, you can avoid the compilation with slightly more code:

```
static public bool Method<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    var memberExp = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    var propertyInfo = memberExp.Member as PropertyInfo;
    var propertyExpression = memberExp.Expression as MemberExpression;
    var targetObject = ((FieldInfo)propertyExpression.Member).GetValue((propertyExpression.Expression as ConstantExpression).Value);

    Console.WriteLine("Old value is {0}", propertyInfo.GetValue(targetObject));

    if (SomeCondition1)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(targetObject, null);
        return false;
    }
}
```